# Multiplying the output of arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to create a console program that multiplies the output of `array1` and `array2` to `array3` in reverse.

```
var array1 = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var array2 = new [] { 12, 14, 15, 16, 17 };
var array3 = new [] { 8, 4, 7, 2, 1 };
```

For example: `array1 * array2` expected output is `array3`.

```
var array1 = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var array2 = new [] { 17, 16, 15, 14, 12 };
var array3 = new [] { 17, 32, 45, 56, 60 };
```

To get the output for array number 3 I need to reverse the values of `array3` and multiple it by the output of `array1` and `array2`. For example: `array3 = {60, 56, 45, 32, 17} * product of array 1 & 2 {17, 32, 45, 56, 60}`.

My problem is I don't have any idea how to multiply the output of arrays 1 and 2 to array 3. So far here is my code:

```
            int[] array1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
            Console.Write("\nArray 1: ");
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", array1));

            int[] array2 = {12, 14, 15, 16, 17};
            Console.Write("Array 2: ");
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", array2));


            int[] array3 = {8, 4, 7, 2, 1};
            Console.Write("Array 3: ");
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", array3));

            Console.Write("\nProduct of array 1 and 2: ");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", array2.Reverse().Zip(array1, (x, y) => x * y)));


            Console.Read();
```

In a [previous iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69263135/multiple-values-inside-array) of this question asked under another account I was given suggestion to use

```
array3 = array2.Reverse().Zip(array1, (a, b) => a*b).ToArray();
```

but I think I want something else as I need "to multiply the output of arrays 1 and 2 to array 3".

Comment: [This question looks very similar...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69263135/multiple-values-inside-array)

Comment: @Sweeper I've edited that into the question so it is at least clear what *did not* work for OP's collection of identities.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. A bit hardcoded but you get the idea. You can use LINQ but you will not learn how to operate arrays yourself, using iterators.

```cs
var a1 = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
var a2 = new int[] {6,7,8,9,10};
var a3 = new int[] {10,20,30,40,50};
var out1and2 = new int[5];
var out3 = new int[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    out1and2[i]  = a1[i] * a2[i];
    out3[i] = out1and2[i] * a3[a3.Length - 1 - i]; // reverse by taking max and subtracting

}
        
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(out1and2[i]);
    
Console.WriteLine("----------------------");

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(out3[i]);
```

> 6
> 14
> 24
> 36
> 50
> ----------------------
> 300
> 560
> 720
> 720
> 500

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            Console.Write("\nArray 1: ");
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", array1));

            int[] array2 = { 12, 14, 15, 16, 17 };
            Console.Write("Array 2: ");
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", array2));


            int[] array3 = { 8, 4, 7, 2, 1 };
            Console.Write("Array 3: ");
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", array3));

            Console.Write("\nProduct of array 1 and 2: ");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", array2.Reverse().Zip(array1, (x, y) => x * y)));
           

            var arr = array2.Reverse().Zip(array1, (x, y) => x * y).ToArray();

            Console.Write("\nProduct of array 2 and 3: ");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", array3.Reverse().Zip(arr, (x, y) => x * y)));


            Console.Read();
```

output will be :
17, 64, 315, 224, 480

Comment: LINQ is a great tool, when you already know how to operate arrays manually